# The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for FormApp.FormResponse.withItemResponse -

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create a prefilled link for a google form.  I get this error - The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for FormApp.FormResponse.withItemResponse when the code hits this area

```
if(items[k].getType().toString() == "PARAGRAPH_TEXT"){
       formItem = items[k].asParagraphTextItem; 
      // I get the error when it hits the line below
     formResponse.withItemResponse(SourceAnswer);
    var urlnext = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
         response = formItem.createResponse(SourceAnswer);
    formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
```

Comment: From `I get the error when it hits the line below`, about `formResponse.withItemResponse(SourceAnswer);` in your script, what is `formResponse` and `SourceAnswer`? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your current issue from your showing script. I apologize for this.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Where is `SourceAnswer` declared?

Answer (score 0):

### A working sample for creating form responses with answers

- From your problem it seems like either `formResponse` or `SourceAnswer` is wrongly declared
- Keep in mind that `SourceAnswer` needs to be the response to a single form item (which you need to specify)
- Keep in mind that you can only create answers to form responses that you create programmatically (opposed to form responses that have been submitted by users - see [withItemResponse(response)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#withitemresponseresponse))
- Also, in the line `formItem = items[k].asParagraphTextItem()` you forgot the `()`

Working sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var formResponse = form.createResponse();
  var items = form.getItems();
  items.forEach(function(item, k){
    if(items[k].getType().toString() == "PARAGRAPH_TEXT"){
      var formItem = items[k].asParagraphTextItem(); 
      console.log("formItem: " + formItem.getTitle())
      var SourceAnswer = formItem.createResponse('my response');
      formResponse.withItemResponse(SourceAnswer).submit();
    }
  })
}
```